# Ruby on Rails - file path is different on development and production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am downloading a file from the **SFTP server** to a **local**.

```
sftp.download!("1.txt", "/public/file.txt")
```

This works on production but on local, I have to add **root** path in front of **the dest file path**.

```
"#{Rails.root}/public/file.txt"
```

Comment: Paths can be different, I guess it depends on the server configuration. What does `Rails.root` return on production? Some times, when using ftp, you have access only to a directory and parents aren't visible, so "/public" might be at the "root" of the folder you have access via ftp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was `/`

This works on development & production.

```
sftp.download!("1.txt", "public/file.txt")
```